# What story had the world being eaten every night by toothy orbs?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I thought it was *The Tommyknockers* by Stephen King, but after a check with Wikipedia, it appears that's not the case.

What I remember about the story (a TV movie I think, but definitely based on a book) was that the world is created anew every night, and that the old, used up, Earth was eaten nightly by some scary creatures.

The major plot point involved some protagonists not getting onto the new world at midnight, and having to escape from the monsters that were eating up yesterday's planet.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I'm finding it very hard to Google for.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Was it [The Langoliers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/)?  It was one of the stories originally published in the collection [Four Past Midnight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451213599)

> On a red eye flight to Boston from LA 10 people wake up to a shock.
>   All the passengers and crew have vanished. When they try to contact
>   the ground they make no connections. They land the plane only to
>   discover that things haven't changed. But its like the world is dead.
>   No one is there, the air is still, sound doesn't echo, the food is
>   tasteless. And a distant sound is heard coming closer. A race of
>   monstrous beings bent on their destruction is heading for them, eating
>   everything in sight.

Comment: Given that he specifies Stephen King and the Langoliers movie fulfills every criteria, this has gotta be it.

Comment: That's absolutely it, thanks so much!

Comment: Definitely langoliers. I've been looking for the name of this film for many years. The story defo fits what I remember of it. Thank u for the loooonnnggggggg awaited answer. Langoliers... would have never remembered that!
Thank you. Regards
Happy person!!
:-)