# Name of a syfy tv movie about passengers on an airplane

Tags: story-identification, tv

Does anyone know a tv movie of the 90s that had 2 parts, and it was about the passengers on a plane that lands in an airport and everyone has disappeared? That's the only thing I remember...

Comment: This was on british telly last week!

Comment: is this kind of question ontopic on thise side or should it be migrated to tv & movies.se?

Comment: @Zaibis Why don't you think it's on topic?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/what-story-had-the-world-being-eaten-every-night-by-toothy-orbs

Answer (score 33):

That sounds like the Steven King movie [The Langoliers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/?ref_=tt_rec_tti):

Most of the passengers on an airplane disappear, and the remainder land the plane in a mysteriously barren airport.

Comment: Damn it, you beat me by 13 seconds!

Comment: This movie is terrible.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Nothing with Bronson "Balki Bartokomus" Pinchot is terrible.

Comment: @WadCheber - agreed. The movie "Second Sight" with Pinchot and John Larroquette is flat-out HILARIOUS!

Comment: But the novella was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Might be [Millennium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_%28film%29), which is based on a great short story by John Varley.

Comment: That was about an airline crash where the passengers were taken off mid-flight. Aside from the airplane, there's really very little in common with the film the OP is describing.

Comment: In "Millenium" the airplane wasn't empty. Please expand the answer by telling us what matches up with the OP's description. Thanks!