# 1980's movie - help?

Tags: story-identification, movie

The earliest Sci-fi movie I recall stars a group of people trying to escape what looks like evil balls - might be evil alien balls taking over. Something along these lines. And it is not *Critters*.

One particular scene stuck in my mind - the group is planning how to escape, and they look up and there's the mountains up top and you can see the power lines dropping - it's the balls (evil, or alien... no idea) coming down.
If anyone recalls anything similar, let me know! Thanks.

Comment: It might be on the list: http://www.80shorror.net/index/2015/10/6/small-creature-movies-of-the-1980s-a-complete-list-gremlins-critters-ghoulies-etc

Comment: Evil floating metal balls?

Comment: Were they controlled by someone/something? The [spheres](https://robbinsrealm.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/phantasm_ball.jpg) controlled by [the tall man](https://nonamemovieblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/p3balls.jpg) in [the phantasm movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasm_(film)) come to mind, but i havent seen them all, and dont remember that scene in particular.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/what-story-had-the-world-being-eaten-every-night-by-toothy-orbs

Answer (score 14):

The evil alien balls, plus the scene with the power lines collapsing on the mountains above suggest that this could be [The Langoliers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/). The people were passengers on an airplane that had fallen through a hole in time into the past, and they were trying to restart the airplane's engines to fly back through the hole and into the present.

The evil alien balls were the titular Langoliers, who consumed everything in the past. The passengers' discovery of this makes them realize that true time travel is impossible.