# Movie from the 80s-90s about an unknown force eating everything on earth?

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is what I can remember of the movie. There was this guy who is running for his life at the same time I think he was trying to find out what this unknown force is. Towards the end of the movie I think it is. The guy gets on a plane at an airport and is trying to take off as this unknown force is eating the airport and runway as he is taking off.

Comment: This is, as usual, The Langoliers

Comment: Thought it might be Neverending Story by the title, but the airport bit does point to The Langoliers.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/what-story-had-the-world-being-eaten-every-night-by-toothy-orbs

Answer (score 14):

As others have pointed out, this is probably the TV miniseries adaptation of *[The Langoliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_(miniseries))*.

> During a red-eye flight of a Lockheed L-1011 from Los Angeles International Airport to Boston Logan International Airport, the plane flies through a strange light, and most of the passengers and flight crew disappear, leaving behind only personal artifacts. Only those passengers who were asleep remain, and discover the predicament when they wake. Pilot Brian Engle, deadheading on the flight, takes the controls; unable to contact any other airport, he decides to land the plane at Bangor International Airport because of its long runway.

....

> As they board, the group witnesses strange creatures emerge from the horizon, consuming everything including the ground. Bob calls these creatures Langoliers, creatures that feed on time which has passed. As a panicked Craig comes running out of the airport, a weak Dinah is able to psychically convince him his meeting has moved from Boston to here. In a hallucinatory state, Craig gleefully admits to his boss he cost his company $43 million, in hopes of escaping his father's abuse. The delay leaves Craig vulnerable and he is eaten by the Langoliers. The plane takes off just as the Langoliers consume the entire airport beneath them. As they fly through the void, Dinah succumbs to her wound and dies while recalling the lines "everything was beautiful, even things that were dead."

### The Flight Scene

Comment: Those seats look amazing

Comment: @AzorAhai They look better than business class in 2020... :(